# Git patch fails when removing binary files

Tags: git, diff, patch, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a patch with Git that removes some .fla and .swf files. When I apply it, like this:

```
$ patch -p1 < 0001-remove-ckeditor-samples.patch
```

I get an error, like this:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

I've tried creating the patch with two different methods:

```
git format-patch -1 <sha>
```

This created a patch like this - http://pastebin.com/uKHLcCh2 - which fails with the error above.

I also tried making the patch like this:

```
git diff <sha> > remove-ckeditor-samples.patch
```

and that gave me a patch like this:

`diff --git a/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.fla b/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.fla
deleted file mode 100644
index 27e68cc..0000000
Binary files a/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.fla and /dev/null differ
diff --git a/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.swf b/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.swf
deleted file mode 100644
index dbe17b6..0000000
Binary files a/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/assets/output_for_flash.swf and /dev/null differ`

This one also fails (same error). Is it possible to create a patch that'll remove these files? How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `git apply` or `git am` instead of `patch`? The patches produced by `git`, while mostly compatible with the older `patch` tool, do utilize some extensions to the patch format in some cases...

Comment: `git apply` does work, yes. I'm really hoping to make this work with the `patch` command, though - the patch is applied by a build script we use, and changing the way that build script applies the patches is a little beyond what I'd like to do here (if it's possible).